# Percentage of a number

Tags: percentages

How can we find out what percentage 2 gigabytes is of 15 gigabytes?

I am not calculating correctly:
2 gb * x (percentage) = 15 gb
x =  15/2

Comment: $2\cdot\frac{100}{15}=13.333\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the *Rule of Three*:

The percentage must be to $100$ what $2$ is to $15$. Now $2$ is to $15$ what $\dfrac2{15}$ is to $1$, which is turn is what $\dfrac{200}{15}$ is to $100$. Hence the simplified answer is $\dfrac{40}3\approx13.33\,\%$.

Answer (score 0):

You're working backwards. You want to find the % of 15, so it's 15*x = 2, or x = 2/15

Comment: You found the fraction.  It would help if you would explain how to convert it to a percentage.